# Django forms extending from model doesn't work

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to create a form that inherits from my model but it doen't work and I can't find out why.

It doesn't throw any exception but simply doesn't shows the specified fields.

models.py

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='/')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
    date = models.DateField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    width = models.IntegerField(max_length=9)
    height = models.IntegerField(max_length=9)
    sold = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s from %s by %s' % (self.name, self.date, self.owner)
```

forms.py

```
class PictureForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        fields = ('picture', 'name', 'date', 'description', 'width', 'height')
```

Am I missing something, or is there a general mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `forms.Form` not `forms.ModelForm`:

```
class PictureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        fields = ('picture', 'name', 'date', 'description', 'width', 'height')
```